# Extract data from json file using grep and sed

Tags: json, shell, grep

I have a **json** file named `output.json`. It has a simple *key:value* format, e.g.:

```
{
    "key":"value",
    "key":"value",
    "key":"value",
    "key":"value",
}
```

I want to extract *"value part"*.

If anyone can write me a command that will be really helpful.

Comment: Better use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for this.

Comment: *stackoverflow* is not a *"do this for me, thanks"* code service, please provide some code example of your attempts to solve this problem on your own and describe what problems you encountered when you tried.

Comment: just don't parse json with grep and alike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (which is *much* better suited for parsing and filtering JSON than `grep`/`sed`/`awk`/etc) you can extract all values with [`values` function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#arrays,objects,iterables,booleans,numbers,normals,finites,strings,nulls,values,scalars):

```
$ echo '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}' | jq '.[]|values'
1
2
3
```

Alternatively (since you mention you already use Python in your pipeline), you can do it like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
my_values = json.load('output.json').values()
```

Comment: I need to use grep. Adding this line in a big python script. I did something lie 

`#grep -m 1 "\"${1}\"" /home/ajay/file.json | sed -r  's/^ *//;s/.*: *"//;s/",?//'`

but its not working

Comment: Why don't you use Python then? (`json.loads("..input..").values()`)

Comment: @ajaysheoran2323, any luck with this answer?

Comment: Yes got the answer. Thanks everyone.